# How to Send a Multipart/Form-Data POST Request with an Attachment in .NET?

Tags: .net, post, postman, httpclient

I have a working Postman POST request where the body consists of one attachment file in `application/json` format, and the content type is `multipart/form-data`:
[image]

However, I need to replicate the same request using `.NET 7`.

I've tried the following code, but it returns a 400 Bad Request in the `httpResponse:`:

```
using var formDataContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
using var content = JsonContent.Create(document); // document - it's an object
content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");
formDataContent.Add(content);

var httpResponse = await _httpClient.PostAsync([my_url], content);
```

My goal is to send a `multipart/form-data` POST request with an attachment in `application/json` format, just like in Postman. What am I doing wrong, and how can I achieve this in `.NET 7`?

Comment: can you confirm that content is not empty in `using var content = JsonContent.Create(document);`. you may need to use other version of [Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.jsoncontent.create?view=net-7.0) method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this query work, I specified the `JsonContent` name and fileName when adding it to `MultipartFormDataContent`:

```
using var formDataContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
using var content = JsonContent.Create(document); // document - it's an object
formDataContent.Add(content, "request", "request.json");
```